# Oauth "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security

I'm working on setting up an Oauth Security configuration with Spring Server, using [this code](https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-14/tree/master/examples/9-VideoServiceWithOauth2) as a guide. I have modified the ResourceServerConfigurationAdapter to look like this, basically adding one class to allow anonymous gets on my API path.

```java
protected static class ResourceServer extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // This method configures the OAuth scopes required by clients to access
    // all of the paths in the video service.
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").anonymous();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/gift/**").anonymous();

        //Other additions will be made that require username/password combinations, but I want to start simple first
    }
```

I go to my server's `/gift` folder via a web browser, and see this error:

```xml
<oauth>
    <error_description>
        An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    </error_description>
    <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

My server console logs shows this:

```
2014-10-24 16:48:32.895  WARN 8908 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource      : ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US
2014-10-24 16:48:32.895  INFO 8908 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Oct 24 16:48:32 EDT 2014, principal=<unknown>, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={message=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext, type=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException}]
```

Googling the error lead to [this site](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#auth-exception-credentials-not-found), which says

> This is a another debug level message which occurs the first time an
>   anonymous user attempts to access a protected resource, but when you
>   do not have an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter in your filter chain
>   configuration.

However, as I can never get a connection, it seems like something is fundamentally wrong. Furthermore, I don't have the slightest clue where I would put an `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` in my filter chain configuration, as I don't have a clue where to even include a filter chain configuration. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
    @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/gift/**").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following filters in web.xml file and try to make worked with new tomcat

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>        
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
```